# Content of iframe always null

Tags: javascript, vb.net, iframe, printing

I have an iframe in my ASP.NET webform and I have print content of this iframe.
Althought I set src for iframe and content show on web page, when I get content of iframe
by JavaScript is always null. I using code below:

```
document.getElementById("printf").contentWindow.print();
```

But I always recieve a message that "Unable to get property 'contentWindow' of undefined or null reference"
Any one can help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you create IFrame then want to print them ... you need to wait for short moment... for browser to respond .. then use print command ..

you can use something like

```
setTimeOut(print(),100)
```